# In the electron vertex function, why is the square of the momentum of the incoming photon negative?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

On page 191 of Peskin and Schroeder, they state:

> Since $q^2<0$ for a scattering process…

where $q$ is the momentum of the incoming photon in the electron vertex function.

[image]

Why is this so? Shouldn’t the square of the momentum of any real photon be zero, and that of a virtual photon be arbitrary?